# Доброго времени суток, проблема с RecyclerView и ListView

Tags: java, recyclerview

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как отобразить полностью список из
RecyclerView в котором прописано меню товаров и мне нужно при добавлении в корзину выводилось картинка и текст в ListView
Я прописал вот такую команду но у меня только выводится текст,что нужно еще добавить чтобы еще выводилось и изображение

```
ListView oder_list = findViewById(R.id.oder_list);

    List<String> menuTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Menu c : MenuActivity.FullmenuList) {
        if (Order.items_id.contains(c.getId())) ;
        menuTitle.add(c.getTitle());

    }
```

Comment: https://coderlessons.com/articles/mobilnaia-razrabotka-articles/primer-android-listview-s-izobrazheniem-i-tekstom

Comment: https://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/listview/listview-icons.php